# How to get two ties of maximum values in my query?

Tags: sql, max, aggregation

I have a database of a music store and I need to extract the max value of purchases from a customer specific to each country. While using `MAX` function, I noticed that I have two ties of maximum values in 'United Kingdom'. So, I need my query to return both the customers for this country.

```
With t1 As (
           Select i.CustomerId, c.FirstName, c.LastName, 
                      i.BillingCountry Country, Sum(i.Total) Totals
             From Invoice i
              Join Customer c
              On c.CustomerId = i.CustomerId
             GROUP BY 1, 4)

Select CustomerId, FirstName, LastName, Country, Max(Totals) TotalSpent
    From t1
    Group By 4;
```

This is the output

[image]

This is what the output should be

[image]

I tried using `TOP` but apparently by workspace does not accept this function. So, Please suggest a solution that does not use this function.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider something like

```
With t1 As (
           Select i.CustomerId, c.FirstName, c.LastName, 
                      i.BillingCountry Country, Sum(i.Total) Totals
             From Invoice i
              Join Customer c
              On c.CustomerId = i.CustomerId
             GROUP BY 1, 4)

Select CustomerId, FirstName, LastName, Country, Totals TotalSpent
    From t1
    WHERE t1.Total = (SELECT MAX(Totals) FROM t1 t2 WHERE t1.Country = t2.Country)
    Group By 4;
```

(I've changed `MAX(Totals)` to `Totals` in your main query's `SELECT` statement and added the `WHERE` clause)

or

```
With t1 As (
           Select i.CustomerId, c.FirstName, c.LastName, 
                      i.BillingCountry Country, Sum(i.Total) Totals
             From Invoice i
              Join Customer c
              On c.CustomerId = i.CustomerId
             GROUP BY 1, 4),
t2 as (
 SELECT Country, MAX(Totals) as Totals
 FROM t1
 GROUP BY Country
)
Select t1.CustomerId, t1.FirstName, t1.LastName, t1.Country, t1.Totals TotalSpent
    From t1 INNER JOIN t2
     on t1.Country = t2.Country and t1.Totals = t2.Totals
    Group By 4;
```

(I've added the t2 CTE, joined it into your main query, and adjusted the main `SELECT` accordingly)

In both cases, I'm trying to select all the customer information where that customer's total is equal to the maximum total for their country. In principle, this should work no matter how many ties there are.

Comment: I think the group by will throw error, as not all columns in group by clause are in select statement. I think you need to modify query to have GROUP BY i.CustomerId, c.FirstName, c.LastName, 
                      i.BillingCountry.

Comment: I left the OP's `group by`s since they didn't mention a problem with them. You're right that they would throw an error in most DBMSes (so I assume OP is using MySql where this is legal), but that seems separate from the question here.

Comment: Unfortunately, I got the same result as before in both of these querires. 
I understand the second one but I see that t2 would contain the first max value only so, it is not going to add any value while joining with t1.

Comment: What RDBMS, are you using ?

Comment: I am sorry, but I can't figure out this question. This is an online assessment and I am working on an online workspace. @VenkataramanR

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "it will contain the first max value only" since the whole concept of a tie is that there is only one max value. In your example, t2 will contain "United Kingdom, 37.62" and joining on both of those being equal will eliminate all the "United Kingdom" values from t1 that aren't 37.62, but leave the two that are 37.62.

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions!

```
select CustomerId, FirstName, LastName, 
       Country, Totals
from (select i.CustomerId, c.FirstName, c.LastName, 
             i.BillingCountry as Country, sum(i.Total) as Totals,
             rank() over (partition by i.BillingCountry over sum(i.Total) desc) as seqnum
      from Invoice i join
           Customer c
           on c.CustomerId = i.CustomerId
      group by i.CustomerId, c.FirstName, c.LastName, 
               i.BillingCountry
     ) ic
where seqnum = 1;
```